# $LANG=C even though I set it in .profile and .xprofile

Tags: debian, xfce, locale

At work I have a bunch of Debian 9 workstations. Default locale is set to `en_US.utf8` on the systems. The default desktop environment is Xfce. There is one user who somehow has `$LANG=C` defined in his Xfce session. This causes various encoding issues as UTF-9 encoded characters are just shown as boxes.

I have tried adding `export LANG=de_DE.utf8` into the `.profile` and `.xprofile`. There is no `.bash_profile`. Additionally I added `export VAR_FROM_PROFILE=1` and `export VAR_FROM_XPROFILE=1` to the respective files. When the user logs in, we can see both variables being defined in a shell, but `LANG` is still set to `C`. Sourcing the `.profile` manually and then opening programs makes them localized in German, so that works.

Something must change the `LANG` variable after sourcing `.profile` and `.xprofile`, but I did not find any occurrence of `LANG` in the dotfiles and in `.config`. What could reset the locale to `C`?

Comment: maybe turn on `sh -x` mode to try to get a trace of what is going on? or `strace` and see if any LANG or LC or locale stuff pops up

Comment: Where would I insert this to capture the output? It seems that Xfce does something on startup with these things.

Comment: maybe `xterm -e "$SHELL -x"` and then see what that shell gets, though if the problem is in the window manager that might require snooping around with `sysdig` or such